# Question on real polynomial in projective space

Tags: polynomials, roots

Hi all I was given this question and desperately in need of help. I am given a homogeneous polynomial of degree 4 of two variables x and y, with real coefficients with **4 real distinct** projective roots i.e. functions $ y = \alpha_ix $ such that substituting in the polynomial gives identically zero function.
I am asked to show via  change of coordinates of x and y to new coordinates (of course non singular with non singular Jacobian) that in the new coordinates I have the polynomial turns into one of
$ x^4 + ax^2y^2+y^4 ; a<-2 $
OR
$ -x^4 + ax^2y^2-y^4 ; a>2 $
I have no real idea how to do this as to what change to find and I am in desperate need for some help all appreciated thanks

SOLVED

Comment: It still is unclear what you mean by "projective roots", since $y = \alpha_i x$ is an equation, not a function. Maybe you mean points $(x:y) \in \Bbb{P}^2(\Bbb{R})$? Anyway, did you try solving the de-homogenised problem first?